# How to configure CLion for ROS2 under Windows WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion, jetbrains-ide, ros2

I am trying to develop ROS2 packaged under Windows WSL using CLion. I searched many methods and they don't work. Could anyone please tell me how to configure? I appreciate everyone's help.

Here is my config now:

[image: Config]

[image: Output]

I attached my configs for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: One comment. I am using the CLion windows executable.